# Java DTOs to TypeScript

Tags: java, javascript, json, typescript, typescript1.4

Does anyone know of a good method to automate converting Java DTOs to TypeScript?
(these objects used in JSON REST APIs)

Is there a methodology, technique or technology which would allow me to do this more quickly and efficiently?

Comment: Actually I was also searching for some Java to TypeScript convertor but  without a success. So I started [typescript-generator](https://github.com/vojtechhabarta/typescript-generator) project on GitHub. It supports generic collections, inheritance etc.

Comment: I'd like to add jtsgen to the list even though this issue is already closed. It is superior since it works as an annotation processor and not runtime based. https://github.com/dzuvic/jtsgen

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a look at some of the more up-to-date `JavaScript` code generators working with Google's [Protocol Buffers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers) at [GitHub: google/protobuf → Third Party Add ons](https://github.com/google/protobuf/wiki/Third-Party-Add-ons) as this is a language-agnostic [Data Transfer Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) technology with strong `Java` focus and heavy user base so using it might be "*quick and efficient*" and solid choice

Comment: Thanks a lot for a good idea! The problem is that I have a big count of an existing java classes (with some kind of inheritance), so it will be not so easy to refactor them all.

Comment: @Dmitry I'm not aware of a ready to use solution, but writing a simple `java source file` (or `java class file`)→`proto message definition file` converter should not be that complex especially when you know the coding conventions etc. used in your code base